# Get last page number from html using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the last page number from a html code:

```
<a aria-label="Page 47" class="pg _act">47</a>
```

url = "https://www.jumia.com.ng/womens-dresses/"

```
def getLastPageNumber(soup):
  number = []
  for item in soup.find_all("a", class_="pg _act"):
    x = item.text
    number.append(x)
  return max(number)

getLastPageNumber(soup)
```

Whenever I run this code, it only returns '1', if I change the url to url = "https://www.jumia.com.ng/womens-dresses/?page=48" , it outputs 48. What I wanted is for it to append the page numbers and return the maximum value.

Comment: Do you only want to get the last page number of this page?

Comment: Yes, I will like to know how many pages it has because I want to scrape 3000 data points. I know the maximum tabs per page for the website is 48.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get this element by `aria-label="Last Page"` and get the number of last page by regex, code here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

url = "https://www.jumia.com.ng/womens-dresses/"
regex = r"page=(.*)#"
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
target_tag = soup.find("a", {"aria-label": "Last Page"})
print(re.search(regex, target_tag.get("href")).group(1))
```

And this gave me:

```
50
```

It's the same as the page:

[image]

Comment: Just perfect. Thanks a lot.